# check the number of class members in constructor

Tags: c++, class, assert

I'm writing a class where I am constantly adding new members (it's a prototype for a project) and I have implemented my own constructor, copy constructor, copy operator, etc... As I add more members I have to remind myself to keep adding them to the constructors and operators and I'm wondering if there is an automatic way of checking if I am including everything.

I implemented a simple solution that involves counting all members in the class declaration and then set up a #define with that value.

```
Class A
{
   int a;
   int b;
   vector<int> c;
   /*3 members*/
}

#define CLASS_A_MEMBERS 3
```

In the constructor I just do something like this

```
A::A( )
{
   int counter=0;
   a=1; counter++;
   b=1; counter++;
   c.clear(); counter++;

   assert(counter==CLASS_A_MEMBERS)
}
```

Great! Whenever I forget to add something I get an assert and the offending place!

Ok, this works... but, is there a more elegant way of doing something like this?

Cheers

Comment: If you're on GCC, there's a specific warning when you don't initialize something. It also encourages you to use member initializers. That's the most elegant way I can think of.

Comment: Also, if your new members always get the same default value, in C++11, you can just do it right in the declaration: `class C { int newMember = 5; };`

Comment: @chris, no, GCC's `-Wunintialized` doesn't warn for uninitialized class members, although I have a patch that mostly works, see http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2972

Comment: @Andre, why are you calling `c.clear()` on a brand new, empty vector?

Comment: @JonathanWakely, I think it's `-Weffc++`. I get it when I forget to add new members to my member initializers. Something like `newMember should be initialized in the member initializers`.

Comment: @chris, Eurgh, I still can't believe people actually use `-Weffc++`, it has far too many false positives ([here](http://gcc.gnu.org/PR16166), [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/PR16168),  [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/PR22395), [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/PR22406)). It insists you initialize types like `std::string` which have perfectly valid default constructors. My patch will make it less brain-damaged, if I ever finish it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, Indeed. I find some of it useful (like forgetting to initialize some things), but I hear you. I just asked about it going on about the rule of three when I didn't even allocate anything.

Comment: @JonathanWakely for no reason at all. just wrote something. it's purely an example.

Answer (score 3):

Don't solve your underlying problem in this way. Instead, solve it by making your class either non-copyable, or trivially (default) copy/assignable. If all your resources are managed by the RAII principle then you can just let the compiler generate all the special constructors/operators for you, and it will generate them correctly no matter what you do to the class.

Comment: Yes, it appears that letting the compiler take care of the constructor, operators & destructor is the best way to go about this.

Comment: I do some default operations in the constructor to avoid calling a initialization function afterwards. Another issue is that the compiler might not know how to handle objects declared as members of a class resulting in shallow copies of allocated memory

Comment: @Andre You need to make your class members do the right thing when copied: For example if you need a deep copy your member should deep copy itself (this means `shared_ptr` may not be the right choice if you need a deep copy).

Answer (score 0):

The code you have still requires you to remember to update `CLASS_A_MEMBERS`, and to add `counter++` to your initializer and copy constructors.

A better solution is to write unit tests, which is a far more powerful solution, because you can use it to test for all sorts of behavior.

There's no way to solve this problem automatically.  When you add a member to a class, you'll have to visit all of the constructors and so on, to make sure they are right.  Text search can find all the places the last member was mentioned, which will be a good reminder for all the places you might have to touch when you add a new one.

Comment: Yes, unit tests are very powerful, but complete overkill for just this kind of reminder. Remember, a unit test for this would not even be easy to write, considering all of the compiler dependent and standard hacking you would need to do to get the value of a variable when it's uninitialized.

Comment: I just have to update CLASS_A_MEMBERS the idea is to have the others fail if I forget to update them. Adding another counter++ becomes second nature when updating the constructors. Actually this is a problem best suited for a static code analysis tool, but...